# Rails .present? works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My Rails app runs fine locally.

But, I'm getting the following error when I try to start my Rails app on Heroku:

```
Sep 17 09:50:27 ndeavor-staging app/web.1:  /app/app/models/workorder.rb:7:in `<class:Workorder>': undefined method `data' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

This is line 7 in workorder.rb:

```
  if ActsAsTenant.current_tenant.data.present?
```

The tenant.data is an hstore type column (not sure that is pertinent).
Some have values in them. Others are blank.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Issue here is that current tenant is nil

Comment: If you want to submit as answer, I will accept it.  Thanks!    PS - I'll have to figure out why current tenant is not nil locally but is nil on Heroku.

Comment: :) you have defined set_current_tenant_through_filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `current_tenant` is `nil` causing the crash.